# LED drive circuitry:

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, led-driver

[image]

What is the importance of R1,R2, transistor and C1 in this attached circuitry.

Comment: What do you think they do?

Comment: R1 to turn off  Mosfet when it is not actively driven. The transistor and R2 is a current limit icircuit.

Comment: What does V(R2) / R2 = I mean to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1 prevents accidental turn on of the MOSFET because MOSFETs have very high input impedance and thus they are prone to pickup noise from outside world. Typical value is 10k but I think 100k may be okay.

R2 along with BC846 NPN BJT provides a feedback network to keep the load current constant: The drain current drops a voltage across R2. If this value exceeds the threshold VBE of the transistor it'll try to pull the gate of the NMOS to ground. This will lead the VGS, thus the drain current, to decrease. So the drop across R2 will decrease and thus the transistor will stop trying to pull the gate to ground. This will lead VGS, and thus the drain current, to increase. And the cycle starts afresh.

C1 is there to supress the spikes when the MOSFET is turned on and off.